# Error en metodos onClick

Tags: java, android

Tengo un error al cual no consigo respuesta ya que, desde mi punto de vista, este código esta bien.

**Codigo XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="¿Cuantos panes desea comprar?"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="incrementar"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="-"
            android:onClick="disminuir"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nombre"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Orden Completa"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ordenS_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Ordenar"
        android:onClick="enviarOrden"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ordenarCafe"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:text="Pedir Cafe" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Codigo JAVA**

```
  package android.curso.coffeshop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Declaramos la variable donde guardaremos la cantidad de panes ordenados

    int cantidad = 0;

    // Creamos un EditText para guardar nuestro nombre

    EditText editName;

    // Creamos un Button para que mantegan el ID del boton

Button ordenarCafe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Intent i = new Intent (this, NewActivity.class);

    ordenarCafe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ordenarCafe);

    ordenarCafe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Le decimos a la app que este EditText se encuentra en el activity_main y tiene esta ID

    editName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
}


    // En esta funcion, primero recibimos los parametros de cantidad y le decimos donde queremos mostrar la cantidad, a continuacion pondremos alli esa cantidad con un setText

    private void mostrarCantidad(int numeroDePanes){
        TextView cantidadTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        cantidadTextView.setText(numeroDePanes);
    }

    // Le restamos y sumamos 1 a la cantidad de panes segun desees

    public void incrementar(View v){
        cantidad = cantidad + 1;

        // Llamamos a la funcion y le pasamos los parametros

        mostrarCantidad(cantidad);
    }

    public void disminuir(View v){
        cantidad = cantidad - 1;
        mostrarCantidad(cantidad);
    }

    // Primero, debemos decir donde se va a mostrar nuestra orden final.
    // Luego recibiremos toda la informacion en un string y lo mostraremos

    private void mostrarPrecio(String mensajePrecio) {
        TextView precioTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ordenS_text_view);
        precioTextView.setText(mensajePrecio);
    }

    // Calculamos el precio, en los parametros recibimos la variable cantidad y el precio lo colocaremos como parametro en la funcion "enviarOrden"

    private int calcularPrecio(int cantidad, int precio) {
        return cantidad * precio;
    }

    // Buscamos el mensaje que va a recibir mostrarPrecio

    public void enviarOrden (View v) {
        mostrarPrecio(crearOrden());
    }

    // Enviamos los parametros de cantidad y su precio
    // Retornamos un mensaje que envie el nombre que coloquemos en el editText, obteniendo su texto y transformandolo en string, la cantidad a traves de la variable
    // El total esta calculado un linea antes y una linea de agradecimiento

    private String crearOrden(){
        int total = calcularPrecio(cantidad, 2);
        return "Nombre: " + editName.getText().toString() + "\nCantidad: " + cantidad + "\nTotal: $" + total + "\nGracias!";
    }

}
```

El problema es que cuando doy Click en incrementar o disminuir (+ o -) la APP se cierra y me da este Error

Error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: android.curso.coffeshop, PID: 30444
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22479) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)  Application terminated.

Comment: De acuerdo al LogCat, el problema sucede en el método mostrarCantidad() , el método setText() no debe ser usado para asignar un valor entero, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema surge al llamar los métodos desde el layout mediante la propiedad `android:onClick`, el llamado es correcto pero lo que realizan dentro estos métodos tiene un error.

```
 public void incrementar(View v){
        cantidad = cantidad + 1;

        // Llamamos a la funcion y le pasamos los parametros

        mostrarCantidad(cantidad);
    }

    public void disminuir(View v){
        cantidad = cantidad - 1;
        mostrarCantidad(cantidad);
    }
```

Este error se encuentra en el método `mostrarCantidad()`, **el error se debe a que no debes usar el método `setText()` para asignar un valor entero, convierte el valor `numeroDePanes` a `String`**,

```
   private void mostrarCantidad(int numeroDePanes){
        TextView cantidadTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        cantidadTextView.setText(String.valueOf(numeroDePanes)); //* Cambio
    }
```

de otra forma el método `setText()` tratará de buscar el id de un recurso que en realidad no existe en el proyecto.

> [setText(int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int))  Establece el texto que se mostrará utilizando
>   un identificador de recurso de cadena.

---

Con respecto a abrir la Activity usando un Intent, esta es la forma correcta de realizarlo:

```
//Intent i = new Intent (this, NewActivity.class);


private Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ordenarCafe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ordenarCafe);

    ordenarCafe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Resolviste uno de mis problemas :D

Comment: ¿Uno? y ¿cual es el otro? @LuisR

Comment: Estoy intentado pasar de un Activity a otro a traves de un onClickListener, el problema es que el onClickListener funciona bien con muchas otras funciones, pero al hacer el paso de activities no funciona.

No se cual es el problema y tampoco se muy bien donde poner el codigo que utilizo

Comment: Eso no especificas en tu pregunta, ¿De que forma lo estas realizando? @LuisR

Comment: Voy a editar la preguntar

Comment: @LuisR agregue en mi respuesta como realizarlo correctamente si deseas declarar una variable "universal" (global) para el intent.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0):

No se ve bien tu código, espero te ayude esto.
Para que puedas darle click a un botón y te muestre una acción(o quieres que haga algo) debes de realizarlo de esta forma:

---

1.- Tiene que instanciar tu boton para que pueda hacer alguna acción:

```
TU_BOTON=(Button)findViewById ( R.id.btn_TU_BOTON );
```

2.- Y después, recien hacer el `OnClickListener`

```
 TU_BOTON.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                //(y acá adentro colocas todo lo que tu botón va a hacer)

        }
    } );
```

---

espero te ayude en algo, seria bueno que describas bien tu problema y pongas más información.